# access a folder with domain service account

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way to access a folder on network share with a service account?

I am using Windows 7 ent.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to access a folder on network share with a service
>   account?

YES

It should prompt you for the credentials when you try to access it, and in there you will enter your Domain username and password.

If your account does not have sufficient security permissions, then you won't be able to access it. Ask your network admin to check to see if you have sufficient permission.

Comment: It does not prompt me just gives me access denied.

Comment: @Maria Bonzonski: then you do not have sufficient permission to access that folder location. On a side note, please provide all these details in your original question when asking.